# Relationships between tables - PArent Child

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-centered-design

Trying to find a better way to show relationships between one main table (parent) to two child tables. The main table has a list of items, selecting one will update the two tables. Right now the concept is to show a muted color for children but looking to see if there is something better. [image: Parent Table (black) Children windows (gray)]

Answer (score 2):

It’s called a master detail screen

[image]
https://www.google.com/amp/s/blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/05/01/master-master-detail-pattern/amp/